# How does polymorphism helps a programmer?

Tags: java, oop

I have been trying to understand importance Polymorphism concept in java.I totally understand concept of Polymorphism that to use a interface's object to call subcalss's method.I have been reading an article.Which states that :

> Letting the Java Virtual Machine determine which method implementation
>   to invoke, based on the actual class of the object, is how you realize
>   the full power of polymorphism in your programs.

So I understood it ,That jvm is so powerful that It can invoke method on the basis of actual class of object.But as I programmer How I am getting any benifit of this as I could have directly created object of subclass and could have call it's method? In any way how does polymorphism makes things easy for a programmer?

Comment: have you used *Lists* / *Sets* ? .While creating new instances of a list or a set, you code to the *interface* or *Class*?

Comment: Should be maybe be migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.org

Comment: [Runtime Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) also allows Interfaces, not just Subtyping/Overriding. (I try to *avoid* inheritance Polymorphism in general, but encourage the usage of interfaces.)

Comment: Is this question not related to programming ? I could't get it. I can't understand real use of polymorphism,If we have such big term for this that jvm can at runtime decide which class's method to call.What's real use of it or how does it help me ?

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar As more of a "conceptual" usage the other site may be more applicable.

Comment: Does's Stackoverflow's What topics can I ask about here states : a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.I thought that it was related to software devlopement

Comment: Abstraction,ploymorphism,Inheritance are basic oop programming concepts. right? So Is't my question applicable for stackoverflow? Should i delete this ppost and should ask it on programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar It's a good question (in my opinion, which could of course turn out to be wrong), but it fits much better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com and will probably to get much better answers there. Hopefully it will get migrated (I flagged this for migration, the flag is still active). You might want log in to *programmers* and check it out. If this question won't get migrated, then it should get reopened here.

Comment: @hyde Thanks for that.? Yes  I will keep checking programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about design practices and design patterns. You may wish to read up on design patterns (like this one for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns ) before you can understand the depth that hides in these concepts. But either way, here's a quick rundown:

Design practice: Design to an interface. Let's say you have a List of objects of an interface, let's say Animal, like this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
```

And after you've put in there some objects of classes that implement the interface, you could then do this for example:

```
for(Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.printNoiseItMakes();
}
```

Should the animal be a Cat then it would print "Meow", but it could be a Dog and print "Woof". The thing is, at the location in the code where you use the interface, you don't want to have to worry about the implementation.